# Regularity of convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

The following result is Proposition 2.4.3 in [1]:

> **Theorem.** Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded convex set with the non-empty interior. Then $\partial K\in C^{1,1}$ if and only if
> there is $r>0$ such that $K$ is the unioin of balls of radius $r$.

**Question.** Do you know who is the author of this result?

Hörmander does not provide any reference.

**Edit.** I am still quite puzzled about the result. The two answers below show that the result was proved in an unpublished PhD from 1957, it was mentioned without a proof or reference in a paper by Kiselman and the first published proof I am aware of appears in Hormander's book. The result is in my opinion very beautiful not entirely trivial so I expect there should be other references.

**I am still waiting for more answers showing other references to published proofs.**

[1] **L. Hörmander**,
*Notions of convexity.*
Progress in Mathematics, 127. Birkhäuser Boston, Inc., Boston, MA, 1994.

Comment: check this? https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kmj/1138039654  -- the author claims at least one direction of the above result as one of the results of his paper....and with convexity, also the converse

Comment: This result (or better said the non trivial implication) follows from a general regularity result for sets of positive reach, stated for the first time without a proof in Federer´s paper on curvature measures (see Remark 4.20). See also the recent paper of Rataj-Zajicek "On the stucture of sets with positive reach" for a description of these results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem 1.3 in:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.4179.pdf

and the historical discussion below it is relevant. The result (in a form that applies without the convexity assumption) seems to first appear in 1957.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, this is the first place where I saw the result being claimed:

C. O. Kiselman. *Regularity classes for operations in convexity theory*. Kodai Math. J. *15*. 1992.

In particular on the first page the author states:

> To  describe   the  simplest   case   of   our  results,   let  $A$   be  a  compact  set  in  $R^n$. If  the  boundary  of  $A$   is   of   class   $C^{1,1}$,  then  $A$   is  a  union  of   Euclidean  balls   with radii   bounded   from   below;   if   $A$   is  convex,   the  converse   holds.

[image: Screenshot of Kiselman's paper]

Comment: I only had a quick look at the paper. Kiselman states the result in the introduction, but does he prove it in the paper? I did not see the proof, but I did not spend much time reading it.

Comment: Oops, I looked at the theorems closely, and it seems that without more careful reading, it's not easy to immediately extract this result (due to a bunch of notation hiding this stuff). But upon reading the paper more closely, it seems that perhaps an even earlier paper should get the credit, though I haven't had a chance to read those references to be certain.

Comment: Is that Esperanto in the abstract?

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Yes, it's Esperanto.  (Only the second time I've seen an Esperanto abstract.)

Comment: Now I'm wondering if it's common for Japanese math journals to accept texts / abstracts in Esperanto... There is also the journal Funkcialaj Ekvacioj ( = "Functional Equations" in Esperanto, apparently), published by the Department of Mathematics of Kobe University.